# PostBack and HttpWebResponse how to solve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a problem I'm currently working on a page that has a template that I complete with data extracted from the database (MS CRM) when loading the page and put some data into the database. I create the URL depending on the value that the given data will fill in the appropriate fields and such other. The site has as if an e-mail template filled in with just downloaded data. There are two buttons send and edit at the time of pressing send button I create an email I use here HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to download the content of the site but HttpWebResponse at the time of calling again as if I am loading the page again and here the problem occurs because the data is re-entered and subsequent records added to the database .... is there any way around this problem ??

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            InsertDataFromCrm();
            of.NavigateUrl = OfferUrl(false);

        }
    }

    public Guid CreateEmail(bool sendEmail)
    {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;


    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();}
```

Comment: You should be posting the relevant data to your code behind and doing a SQL insert, I have no idea why you would want to make web requests to your web site in your web application.

Comment: How can I download the current html from the website with the data included that are added dynamically depending on the user and send it as an e-mail ?? I have not added that this is an email template that can be sent immediately, or edited and sent